# Update R in Ubuntu xenial

Tags: r, installation, ubuntu

I am working in Ubuntu Xenial with R v 3.2.3. I am trying to updated to the last version of R since I need to install the rgdal package to work with raster data in RStudio but I can't manage. I have tried already those options. After completing all the steps I runn R --version in terminal and it keeps showing R v.3.2.3

https://www.biostars.org/p/88651/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476713/how-to-upgrade-r-in-ubuntu

Any idea about how to do it?

---

```
$ sudo apt-get update
    Reading package lists... Done
    E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
    E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:53
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:53
```

---

I pasted the sources on the sources.list

[image]

The output of

```
 $ sudo apt-get update

Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Comment: This isn't a GIS question so you should look for help elsewhere.

Comment: Probably you need a CRAN added to your sources.list https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/  (I found this terribly difficult until I learnt by various accidents, editing that file also requires root as it's owned)

Comment: I'm using R for RS and GIS analysis. That is why I selected this forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First put:

deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/

or:

deb http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/

in your sources.list.

Then:
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E084DAB9

gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -

Last:

sudo apt-get remove r-base

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install r-base

sudo apt-get install r-base-dev

To fix problem with sources.list do:
Edit your sources.list by: sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
and make it look like:

deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

deb http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/

save and run sudo apt-get update

Comment: Hi, I have been following your steps. Once I complete them, I run again R --version and the output is still the same as at the begining

Comment: If you do not get any errors - you should check that you do not have any other repositories for R - both in /etc/apt/source.list and /etc/apt/source.list.d/  If you have - delete them. and run the apt-get update, apt-get upgrade

Comment: By the way - there was and error in your link. Cut and paste the right repository into your source.list. The problem here is that apt-get is not reading from the right repository.

Comment: I use: deb https://cran.uib.no/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/  And I have the same ubuntu version and everthing works fine. I had an issue with the key, but if you do not have an error when running apt-get update that might not be a problem for you.

Comment: In my source.list I have deb https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ AND # deb-src https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ AND deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/

Comment: I think you should try to comment out the other repository and only use the last one. Look at the output from apt-get update and see if you have a "Hit https://cran.uib.no xenial/ Packages"

Comment: I edited the question to show you the output of apt-get update

Comment: There is something wrong with your sources.list. Move it with: sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list_old
Then do: sudo software-properties-gtk  to reset it. Then follow the instructions above. sudo apt-get update should produce something like:   Fetched 6 845 kB in 8s (854 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: I manage to run sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list_old (nothing happend, just a new command line). When running sudo software-properties-gtk, I got the message 'command not found'

Comment: I updated my answer. See the last part

Comment: im using nano instead of gedit. When doing sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list the file is empty (black screen, only the control options get help, write out etc)

Comment: Yes that is correct. Cut and paste the lines in the answer.

Comment: I update the question to show you the output

Comment: Your dpkg lock file is locked. Close the application that is locking it - or just reboot

Comment: after sudo reboot I have 'Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory Failed to talk to init daemon.

Comment: Wow - fail on reboot? sudo halt? Maybe you should look elsewhere to fix your computer. -f (force) is an option, but I do not know if that is a good idea or not....